# Normalize specified columns in dplyr by value in first row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with four rows, 23 numeric columns and one text column. I'm trying to normalize all the numeric columns by subtracting the value in the first row.

I've tried getting it to work with mutate_at, but I couldn't figure out a good way to get it to work.

I got it to work by converting to a matrix and converting back to a tibble:

```r
## First, did some preprocessing to get out the group I want
totalNKFoldChange <- filter(signalingFrame,
                            Population == "Total NK") %>% ungroup

totalNKFoldChange_mat <- select(totalNKFoldChange, signalingCols) %>%
    as.matrix()

normedNKFoldChange <- sweep(totalNKFoldChange_mat,
                            2, totalNKFoldChange_mat[1,])

normedNKFoldChange %<>% cbind(Timepoint = 
                              levels(totalNKFoldChange$Timepoint)) %>% 
    as.tibble %>%
    mutate(Timepoint = factor(Timepoint,
                              levels = levels(totalNKFoldChange$Timepoint)))
```

I'm so certain there's a nicer way to do it that would be fully dplyr native. Anyone have tips? Thank you!!

Comment: Please add your data using `dput()`.

Comment: Unfortunately the data are proprietary. I would upload a toy dataset, but thankfully someone was able to provide a helpful response without one. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to  `normalize all the numeric columns by subtracting the value in the first row`, use `mutate_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~ .- first(.)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Can you explain why the second argument is a single entry list with a formula? I'm still having some trouble wrapping my head around the dplyr syntax

Comment: @Geoff Previously, the sytax would be `funs(. - first(.))`, but now `funs` got deprecated and in place, it is `list(`. Here the `.` refers to the column values and the `first(.)` is the first value of that column.  Basically subtracting the column with the first value for normalization

Comment: Ahh I see! I had tried `.-first(.)` but got an error I couldn't interpret, didn't realize I could fix it just by making it a list haha